# how can I access to insted div in a webpage after I selected parent div with selenium python

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, save-image

I hope you are all doing fine. I am totally new to Selenium and I am trying to save all images, as well as the text description of each image, on each page of the Realself website. This is what I found in the inspect mode of the website:

```
<div class="fixed-img2">
 <div content="//fi.realself.com/340/2b7d179ededf559f87b06202a9187ee1/0/8/4/Injectable-Fillers-after-3292504-2757399.JPG" alt="Facial Rejuvenation with Injectable Fillers Facial rejuvenation was softly done over a course of 2 years to achieve a very natural and balanced" index="2" hide-icon="true" set-of-images="[&quot;\/\/fi.realself.com\/340\/ff348ae5be9e09ede726574260fa386e\/5\/6\/2\/Injectable-Fillers-before-3292504-2757398.JPG&quot;]" regwall-override="true">
  <div class="Overlay--responsive">
    <div class="Overlay Overlay--explicitVideo Overlay--explicitBlock u-backgroundTransparent ng-hide" data-gtm="{&quot;event&quot;:&quot;safe-mode-block-click&quot;,&quot;safeMode&quot;:false}" ng-click="toggle()" ng-show="vm.blocked" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="true">
      <div ng-show="!vm.hideIcon" class="Overlay-explicitIcon ng-hide" style="" aria-hidden="true">
        <svg icon-id="nsfw-icon" class="Icon Icon--size56x56"><!----><use ng-if="$ctrl.iconURL" xlink:href="#rs-svg-nsfw-icon"></use><!----></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="Overlay-explicitTextBlock ng-hide" ng-show="vm.textmode" aria-hidden="true">
        <span class="Overlay-text Overlay-explicitTextBlack"> Sensitive content </span>
        <span class="Overlay-text Overlay-explicitTextBlack"> Click for real patient photos </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
      <img src="//fi.realself.com/340/2b7d179ededf559f87b06202a9187ee1/0/8/4/Injectable-Fillers-after-3292504-2757399.JPG" class=" lazyloaded" data-src="//fi.realself.com/340/2b7d179ededf559f87b06202a9187ee1/0/8/4/Injectable-Fillers-after-3292504-2757399.JPG">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

I used the command blow to select all element of "fixed-img2"

```
images = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "fixed-img2")
```

After selecting all image elements, I need to loop over them. Inside the child div, I need to save the image with the content attribute. Based on the index attribute value, I need to separate them into before and after images, and at the end, save the image description with the alt attribute.

this is the realself website page:
https://www.realself.com/photos/dermal-fillers#page=3&tags=&location=2038

is this overally a good way to save the images on each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If seems `ALT` attribute don't change in the after image. SO you can add some string to with `ALT` value.

Here is the code to get the list of items. Now you can use your code to Save those value.

Before:

```
listImageCONTENTBefore =[item.get_attribute("content") for item in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.fixed-img2 >div[content*='before']")
listImageALTBefore =[item.get_attribute("alt") + "_before" for item in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.fixed-img2 >div[content*='before']")
```

After:

```
listImageCONTENTAfter =[item.get_attribute("content") for item in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.fixed-img2 >div[content*='after']")
listImageALTAfter =[item.get_attribute("alt") + "_after" for item in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.fixed-img2 >div[content*='after']")
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response. Unfortunately, when I test your suggestion I got this error:

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator

Comment: @mortezaeskandarian, Sorry my bad. Try the updated code.